# Magento showing two currencies

Tags: css, magento, currency-formatting

On my magento shop I have a tiny problem which is probably simple but I can't figure it out.

When I visit the frontpage I have catagories listed, and its show the correct currency (kr.) but when I mouse over it, it changes to krDKK. That is the same thing, but kr. is what we use for danish customers and DKK is the international way.

I hope anyone can help me :)

Comment: Before you ask question here, you must provide your try first, So please share your problem and share the code where you think is a problem

Answer (score 0):

Magento has this defect are 2 controllers(root.xml, locale.xml), sometimes they change.

Change in:

```
magento-admin>System>Manage Currency>Simbols
```

Or/and - `magento-root>lib>Zend>Locale>Data`

`root.xml` or/and `ko_KR.xml`

Change the way you prefer to display in xml.